# stereoscopic illustration

Tags: illustration, 3d

I want to convert my illustration (created with AI) into stereo 3d (Red/cyan anaglyph). I basically want to assign depths to each object relative to each other in postcard fashion and then generate the anaglyph. Could someone recommend me a way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Duplicate your objects. Outline one in red, the other in Cyan. Shift them to achieve the desired 'depth' you are looking for.

Comment: An amendment: quick googling says "cyan left, red right" for towards the viewer, "cyan right, red left" for away from viewer. No offset = base focal plane. The {distance from focal plane} is proportional to {the amount of color shift}

Comment: That's assuming the objects are white-outlined shapes with no fill. A more general method would be to offset the red and cyan components of the object. One way to do this is to isolate each object/depth layer in Photoshop and move the red channel vs the cyan channel (green channel +  blue channel).

Comment: Yea, if you don't want to use a line drawing style, you'll have to do as Lese mentions and bring each 'layer' of the 3d space into Photoshop. I'm not sure if shifting the channels will be enough (there may not be enough red or cyan info in each channel depending on the image itself). You may have to desaturate the image, then either duplicate that to each channel, or create two layers, coloring them and shifting them.